# mysql field has time in hex, need all records in last 24 hours

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm somewhat new to mysql, but after looking at a lot of SO samples related to hexadecimal values in a database, converting from hex to decimal, then retrieving all records added in the last 24 hours, I thought this would succeed -- **thetimestamp** in the query below is the time each record was added, and it is a hex value:

```
      $query = "SELECT * FROM mytable"  
    . " WHERE timediff(NOW(), CONV(thetimestamp, 16, 10)) < '24:00:00'";
```

In reading various SO examples, there are a lot of ways to get the records added in the most recent 24 hours, this one seemed the best to use, because if I can just get my hex time value from the database into decimal, the above will work I suspect.

My issue is that the database I have to work with stored its time in hexadecimal, in the field shown in my query above, **thetimestamp**.

I thought using CONVERT as I've done above would convert each record's **thetimestamp** from hex to decimal so that the call to timediff() would succeed.

I get a valid result resource when I run the query but zero records are found matching my query, despite the fact that records have been added in the past 24 hours.

Am I using CONV() wrong here?

Comment: I am looking at a DB right now that has it's timestamps as dateTime and as hex.... drives me crazy.

Comment: Convert those things before you go totally insane. I can't think of a reason why it would make sense for them to be in a non-native datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CONV()` will give you an `INTEGER`, not a `DATETIME`. You'd have to use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` on it, or just use plain math:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - CONV(thetimestamp, 16, 10) < 86400
```

and then go find the person that decided to store the timestamp in hex and beat them with a stick until they promise to never do it again.

Comment: I must be getting close, but I'm on a Windows 8.1 machine local web server, I'm getting a null query result, maybe because the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() is not implemented on xampp for Windows...?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is once you call `CONV()`, you end up with an integer. Therefore, you're comparing `NOW()` which is a `DATETIME` against an `INT`.

You need to include `FROM_UNIXTIME()` or something similar:

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM mytable"  
. " WHERE timediff(NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(CONV(thetimestamp, 16, 10))) < '24:00:00'";
```

Hope that helps.